# Typescript: How does `Parameters<F>` keep arguments' names?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following piece of code:

```
const f = (a: number, b?: string) => 2;

type ParametersOfF = Parameters<typeof f>; // [number, string?]
type AsTuple = [number, string?]; // [number, string?]

declare function g(...args: ParametersOfF): number; // function g(a: number, b?: string): number !!!
declare function h(...args: AsTuple): number; // function h(args_0: number, args_1?: string): number
```

So `ParametersOfF` and `AsTuple` are the same type. But when I define functions which take args these 2 tuples, `g` have well defined argument names `a` and `b`, while `h` has `args_0` & `args_1`.

Hence the title of this post: `Parameters<F>` is not a simple tuple, it contains also the names of each element in said tuple. Looking at how `Parameters` is defined doesn't help, it's quite simple. So what's the magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason has to do with compiler internals not so much with the `Parameters` type itself. Any similar conditional type you write will preserve parameter names.

For tuples extracted from parameters , the compiler keeps a reference to the original parameter each tuple item was extracted from. When the tuple is spread back to a function the original name is used.

This association is not something directly visible from the type system and there is no way to set this tuple item name, it's a hidden property of the tuple.

Comment: documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters), "Note that when a tuple type is inferred from a sequence of parameters and later expanded into a parameter list, the original parameter names are used in the expansion (however, the names have no semantic meaning and are not otherwise observable)."